# my script in google does not work

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to learn how to write scripts in google. I wrote the following scripts in Google Drive:

```
 function doGet() {
 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
 "<form action='http://www.google.com' method='get' id='foo'></form>" + 
 "<script>document.getElementById('foo').submit();</script>");

 }
```

When I run it, nothing appears! 
Can anybody help me?

Comment: This is a dupe of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272748/how-to-open-a-given-url/13290663#13290663). This behavior was purposefully changed. You can see some alternatives in the response there.