# How to open a website using Google Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a Google script to log some user data, such as date, userId, and the link that he has clicked, and then to open the associated clicked link for him. I wrote the following script:

```
function doGet() {

var ss =SpreadsheetApp.openById('????').getSheets()[0];
var range = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 3);
var mm=Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId();
var values = [[new Date(), mm,'diigo']];    
range.setValues(values);    
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('hello').evaluate();  
}
```

And in hello.html I wrote:

```
<html>
<a href="http://www.diigo.com> HTMLgoodies </a>  
</html>
```

But it does not open the diigo site, while it records information.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you trying to automatically open the link for the user? The above sample should only show a link to the user.

Comment: It seems you forgot to close quotes on the `a href`. Have you checked that?

Comment: Yes. I want to open the link automatically. Do you have any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

See this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272748/how-to-open-a-given-url/13290663#13290663). Short answer is that you can't auto open windows in Apps Script. There are some alternatives posted in that response.